# Unable to send email when under Docker environment

Tags: windows, docker, asp.net-core

I'm unable to send an email when under Docker environment but if I tried running my application outside of Docker. It works.

I tried exposing the SMTP port from Docker but still failed

Here is my email function:-

```
    SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("myhost", 587);
    client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
    client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("email@example.com", "password");             

    MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage();
    mailMessage.From = new MailAddress("email@example.my");
    mailMessage.To.Add(email);
    mailMessage.Body = "message";
    mailMessage.Subject = "Subject";
    mailMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;
    client.Send(mailMessage);
```

I got a "Socket Exception: This is usually a temporary error during hostname resolution and means that the local server did not receive a response from an authoritative server."

Comment: IIUC the container is unable to resolve `"myhost"`. The issue is not that the container should publish the port (`587`) but that it needs to access that port on a host called `myhost`. One option is to run the container using `docker run .... --net=host ...` so that the container can access the host's networking. Then you could access the host using `SmtpClient(localhost, 587)`. Alternatively, provide a fully-qualified (resolvable) domain name for `"myhost"` so that the container can resolve it.